# Can I catch http errors when using jQuery to modify styles?

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling

If I use jQuery to set the background image of the page like so:

```
$('body').css({
    "background-image": 'url(' + myImageUrl + ')'
});
```

How can I detect and handle HTTP errors (500, 503, 404, etc) that might be returned from the image URL?

I did find a jQuery `.error()` method that registers a callback, but it's marked as deprecated in 1.8 with no indication of what is supposed to replace it. (I also can't seem to get it to work, deprecated or not.)

---

Based on the comments and the answer below I tried this variation and it seems to work, but the answer is getting down-votes. Is there a reason this is bad?

```
$('<img>').error(function(obj) {
    alert('error');
}).load(function() {
    $('body').css({
        "background-image": 'url(' + myImageUrl + ')'
    });
}).attr('src', myImageUrl);
```

Comment: `.error()` would not catch that anyway. Only way to make sure would to preload the image and see if it loads. After that apply it to the bg image.

Comment: you could always make a ajax request to check first but that would create possible overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

jQuery

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/xhV4H/)

```
var $image = $("<img />");
$image.on("error",function() { 
  $('body').css({
    "background-image": 'url(defaultimage.jpg)'
  });
}).on("load",function() {
  $('body').css({
    "background-image": 'url(' + myImageUrl + ')'
  });
}).attr("src",myImageUrl);
```

JavaScript:

```
var image = new Image();
image.onerror=function() { 
  document.body.style.backgroundImage="url(defaultimage.jpg)"
}
image.onload=function() {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage="url("+myImageUrl+")"
}
image.src=myImageUrl;
```

Comment: No idea why the down-votes. It's a sound idea imo. The only downside is loading the image twice, which should be minimal impact considering caching. I don't need the default image bit, but it's a nice touch. Thanks.

Comment: Great -  Yes, the image should come from cache